# Can RabbitMQ transfer a message only after a monitored condition becomes true

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, event-driven

Can RabbiMQ or any other queuing service do the following usecase?

1. A customer (Server #1) uploads a data folder to a storage server (Server #2).
2. The customer then wants to request an analysis server (Server #3) to monitor the folder and start analyzing the data only when it completes the upload.

Server #1 doesn't track the upload's status. It sends the folder's details to the queue  shuts down.

The only thing that Server #3 knows is that once a message is available, it gets the folder details and start analyzing it.

So,

Is it possible for RabbitMQ, or a known design pattern, to hold on to the message, check and recheck the condition until it is true and publish the message to Server #3 only when the folder is finally available.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately NOT ... RabbitMQ or for that matter any general purpose queue is designed for message routing and specialize in guaranteed delivery of messages from the producer to the consumer.

Such conditional consumption of messages ideally should be handled at the application level where the consumer on receiving the messages waits on a handler for completion of such conditions for consumption post that the message is processed to completion.